What does "She human or the other thing" mean?
From John Le Carre's Smiley's People:

A deep, masculine voice, very slow, issued out of the darkness behind her. “What is it, Hils?” growled the voice. “Bogweevil, budgie, or giraffe?”
The question was followed by a slow thud like the movement of cloth over something hollow.
“It’s human, Con,” Hilary called over her shoulder, and went back to looking at her brogues.
“She human or the other thing?” the voice demanded.
“It’s George, Con. Don’t be cross, Con.”

Does that mean "is that a female or male person" or "is that a person or an animal"?

Yes, it seems to be an idiosyncratic way of asking  "Is it a woman or a man?"
It would have been clearer if the author had hyphenated it - She-human. She-dog is a traditional way of referring to a female dog, to avoid saying bitch.

According to the preview on Google Books, the "she" is italicized - presumably for emphasis.

Rather than 'she-human', I think Con is asking "[Is] she human or the other thing?"

@user20936 But that was already answered in the previous line. So this question seems to be asking what kind of human.

It is rather baffling taken out of context. George Smiley has arrived at a pet's boarding house, run by Con (Connie) and Hils (Hilary). They are a she-human couple, and George is the other thing. Connie knows George; they used to work together, but she retired. This is awkward repartee.
